# Button event not firing on one click when it ends or starts

Tags: c#, wpf

My app is working fine but I miss a click. When I reach the end of a list and want to go to the previous item, I want to press twice the previous button one click is missed. Same for previous button when it reaches from last item to first here is my code for student class.

```
public student(string Firstname,string Lastname,string City)
{
    this.Firstname = Firstname;
    this.Lastname = Lastname;
    this.City = City;
}
public static List<student> listofstudents = new List<student>();
public static int i = 0;
```

I am just adding students in list using this code.

```
private void btnCreateStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   student.listofstudents.Add(new student(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, 
                                                          txtCity.Text));
   txtCity.Clear();
   txtFirstName.Clear();
   txtLastName.Clear();
   student.i = -1;
}
```

My code for next button

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    student.i++;
    if (student.i < student.listofstudents.Count )
    {             
        txtFirstName.Text = student.listofstudents[student.i].Firstname;
        txtLastName.Text = student.listofstudents[student.i].Lastname;
        txtCity.Text = student.listofstudents[student.i].City;           
    }

    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("list is full");
    }

}
```

My code for previous button

```
private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    student.i--;
    if (student.i >=0)
    {                 
        txtFirstName.Text = student.listofstudents[student.i].Firstname;
        txtLastName.Text = student.listofstudents[student.i].Lastname;
        txtCity.Text = student.listofstudents[student.i].City;
    }
    else
    {          
        MessageBox.Show("no data");
    }
}
```

Comment: How fast do you click? Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe the exact steps to reproduce?

Comment: Suppose first I Create four students and add them to the list.i press the next button to reach at the last student and when i want to go to the previous students i have to press twice the previous button then it works.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the `btnPrevious_Click`, is it executed twice? If so, check the value of `i` for each execution. Also, do you mean you press "next" until you reach the last student or until the `MessageBox.Show("list is full");` is hit?

Comment: its executed twice.  i press "next" until message.show is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a simple logic error. Lets assume you had only two student entries and you go forth and back as you described:

```
[button next clicks]
i = 0 --> show first student data
i = 1 --> show second student data
i = 2 --> show message and still show unchanged second student data

[button previous clicks]
i = 1 --> show second student data (that where already visible from i = 2)
i = 0 --> show first student data
```

The solution is simple: whenever you show a message box, you keep showing the student data from the previous `student.i` value. So you should undo the change to `student.i` when going out of range:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    student.i++;
    if (...)
    { ... }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("list is full");
        student.i--; // undo change
    }
}

private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    student.i--;
    if (...)
    { ... }
    else
    {          
        MessageBox.Show("no data");
        student.i++; // undo change
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right man @grek it a logic error when i press the previous button its was showing twice thanks :)